# Identifying none value from column

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading csv using pandas to perform some analysis on it. Where I am getting this error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'none'
```

I checked, I am getting this error due to `shift_zip` parameter. I manually went to csv file and openoffce and converted this column to numeric. But still it gives this error.

Data looks like this

[image]

I manually checked `shift_zip` column but can not find none value in it.

I also tried to print this column data and it's data type, which gives `<class int>`.

```
for val in data['nurse_zip']:
#     print((val))
    if type(val) != 'int':
        print(type((val)))
```

output

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

How to I correctly identify which is none value in this column is causing this issue?

Edit 1: Adding more code for better understanding:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("model__newdata.csv",header = 0)


#Data Pre-processing
data = dataset.drop('shift_location_id',1)
data = data.drop('status',1)
data = data.drop('city',1)
data = data.drop('open_positions',1)
# data = data.drop('shift_id',1)
# data = data.drop('role_id',1)
# data = data.drop('specialty_id',1)
# data = data.drop('years_of_experience',1)
# data = data.drop('shifts_zip',1)
# data = data.drop('nurse_zip',1)
# data = data.drop('shift_department_id',1)
# data = data.drop('shift_organization_id',1)
# data = data.drop('user_id',1)


#Find median for features having NaN
median_role_id, median_specialty_id = data['role_id'].median(),data['specialty_id'].median() 
median_shift_id = data['shift_id'].median()
median_specialty_id = data['specialty_id'].median()

data['shift_id'].fillna(median_shift_id, inplace=True)
data['role_id'].fillna(median_role_id, inplace=True)
data['specialty_id'].fillna(median_specialty_id, inplace=True)
data['years_of_experience'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
data['shifts_zip'].fillna(0, inplace=True) #Gives none value error
data['nurse_zip'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
data['shift_department_id'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
data['shift_organization_id'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
data['user_id'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

print (data[data['nurse_zip'] == 'none'])
```

Output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [shift_id, user_id, shift_organization_id, shift_department_id, role_id, specialty_id, years_of_experience, nurse_zip, shifts_zip]
Index: []
```

**Edit 1**

Result on jezrael answer

It give `False` or `True` as per condition. Can not check which particular row is none or empty.

Comment: Please paste the output of `data['shifts_zip'].dtypes`

Comment: @hacker315: it gives `object `

Answer (score 2):

If finding the Na or null value is the objective then simply use

```
df.info()
```

and you will be able to see the datatype of the column as well as the None value count also.

But I think, in your dataset the value which making noise is not in null format.
You can give a try to below points.
1:Better you visualize the particular column using historical plot or any other plot.
2:Use df[column].astype to force change the dtype of column

Comment: it gives `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'info'` when I tried `ata['nurse_zip'].info()`

Comment: Use data.info() or you can also use data['feature_name'].describe() and share the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
#check string none
print (data[data['nurse_zip'] == 'none'])

#check non integer values
print (data[data['nurse_zip'].apply(type) != int])

#check strings values
print (data[data['nurse_zip'].apply(type) == str])

#check missing values values
print (data[data['nurse_zip'].isnull()])
```

Comment: I have edited my question with code details and output. Can you please check. `data[data['nurse_zip'] == 'none']` why we need to write data[data['nurse_zip']] rather then `data['nurse_zip']`

Comment: @JhonPatric - are data confidental?

Comment: @JhonPatric - Do you test all 3 my solutions?

Comment: Thanks for these solutions. I tried them all. Please check my update in Q for result

Comment: @JhonPatric - So is necessary check missing values? `print (data[data['nurse_zip'].isnull()])` ?

Comment: I appreciate, but `print (data['shifts_zip'].isnull())` prints first 29 rows as `False` then `...` and then lat 29 rows as `Falses`. It does not show result of remaining rows in jupiter notebook. Also even if it say, checking 58000 records for True or false manually will be very difficult

Comment: @JhonPatric - yes, but my code is different, not `print (data['nurse_zip'].isnull())`, but `print (data[data['nurse_zip'].isnull()])` - filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Okay sorry for that, your code gives this result `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [shift_id, user_id, shift_organization_id, shift_department_id, role_id, specialty_id, years_of_experience, nurse_zip, shifts_zip]
Index: []`

Comment: @JhonPatric - So all my solution return empty df ?

Comment: Yes it give empty

Comment: @JhonPatric - so it seems some data related problem, is possible send me data to my email from my profile if not confidental?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190362/discussion-between-jhon-patric-and-jezrael).